# Binding Collection SubProperty update

Tags: wpf, properties, observablecollection

I am having problems updating the values ​​of a Listview that makes binding a ObservableCollection Sub property,

My Principal ViewModel

```
public class ClienteViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
...
    public ContatoViewModel ContatoViewModel
    {
      get
      {
         contatoViewModel = new ContatoViewModel(db,ClienteSelecionado);
         return contatoViewModel;
      }
      set
      {
         this.contatoViewModel = value;
         RaisePropertyChanged("ContatoViewModel");
      }
   }
}
```

Secundary ViewModel

```
 public class ContatoViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
      public ObservableCollection<Contato> Contatos{
           // list values 
           }

      public ICommand addContato{get;set;}

      public ICommand removeContato{get;set;}

      public Contato SelectedContato{get;set;}


    }
}
```

XAML:

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ContatoViewModel.Contatos},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged">
```

or

```
 <ListView DataContext="{Binding ContatoViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Contatos,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
```

or

```
 <Grid DataContext="{Binding ContatoViewModel}">
  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Contatos,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
 </Grid>
```

Values ​​are displayed normally, but when I insert some value in and call raisePropertyChanged ObservableCollection (), updated nothing.

But if the list is in ViewModel Main functions normally. What should I do to make it work with a subproperty?